# Exception Handling When Using Spring OAuth2 Client Enabled WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, exception, webclient, oauth2client

I have an OAuth2 enabled **WebClient** configured using Spring's very convenient [spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2) library. It works perfectly in terms of getting and managing tokens when I make requests to my OAuth2 secured resource server API

I'd like to add global exception handling to the WebClient to handle exceptions arising from requests to my resource server. An **ExchangeFilterFunction** following something like the approach outlined in [this article](https://careydevelopment.us/blog/spring-webflux-how-to-handle-errors-with-webclient) looks good.

I'm just wondering, as the WebClient already has a **ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction** applied, would adding additional filters have any impact on the interactions with the OAuth2 authorization server?

Here is my current WebClient config:

```
@Bean
public WebClient edmsDataIntegrationServiceWebClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
    oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("my-auth-server");

    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(baeUrl)
            .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
            .build();
}
```

So the additional filter would be something like the approach outlined [here](https://careydevelopment.us/blog/spring-webflux-how-to-handle-errors-with-webclient), where *handleResourceServerError()* would return an **ExchangeFilterFunction** that handles exceptions caused by my resource server response:

```
return WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(baeUrl)
        .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
        .filter(WebClientFilter.handleResourceServerError()) //handles exceptions caused by resource server response
        .build();
```

Is the above approach ok without breaking any of the ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction functionality?